# How to catch undefined rule in lex

Tags: posix, lex

Say i have some rules and actions, like so

```
,                   { do something; }
\.                  { do_something; }
\(                  { do_someting; }
\)                  { do_something); }
:                   { do_something; }
...
```

Whenever i match the a rule on the left, the action on the right gets called.
But what if i want to match everything else ? How could i do that?

using something like

```
.*          { do_something; }
```

won't work because it also applies to the above rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the lex spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/lex.html#tag_20_65_13):

> During pattern matching, lex shall search the set of patterns for the
>   single longest possible match. Among rules that match the same number
>   of characters, the rule given first shall be chosen.

So I would go with:

```
.  { do_something; }
```

...and put it as the last rule.

This will match a single character, except for newline ("A <newline> shall not be matched by a period operator").  If you also want to match newline:

```
.|\n  { do_something }
```

Finally, if you do not actually want to consume the character, you need an extended regular expression (ERE) that matches the empty string.  You could try:

```
.{0}  { do_something }
```

As I read the spec for lex and EREs, I believe that should work, but it would not surprise me if it tickled some bug somewhere :-)

Comment: Indeed did not seem to work. Say for instance, i want to catch a '&' or a '^'. They are both one character long, so . would pick them up as if they were \( or any other single char laying around. I am guessing what I have to do is, when catching a character, see if there's a token for it or not.

Comment: Yes, but the lex spec I quoted says the _longest_ match wins, and it says if multiple rules match the same length, then the _first_ match wins.  So `.` as the last rule, since it only matches one character, can only be the chosen match if no other rule matches.

Comment: Then i must be doing something awefully wrong :) thanks for the answer though. +1